# How to bind a vb.net ComboBox to related tables

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, relational-database

I am developing a Windows Form Application against a SQL Server relational database.  An example of the database schema is:

```
TableA
------------------
PK  A_ID    uniqueidentifier
    A_NAME  varchar(254)

TableB
------------------
PK  B_ID    uniqueidentifier
FK  A_ID    uniqueidentifier
    B_NAME  varchar(254)

TableC
------------------
PK  C_ID    uniqueidentifier
FK  A_ID    uniqueidentifier
    C_NAME  varchar(254)
```

In the form I have a ComboBox (`cboA_ID`) to select the `TableA` record (DataSource = TableA, DisplayMember = A_NAME, ValueMember = A_ID) and a TabControl where controls on each tab are bound to fields in either `TableB` or `TableC`.

My question is, is it possible to bind `cboA_ID` to `TableB.A_ID` and `TableC.A_ID`?

This is my first database application so if there is a better way to do this I'm all ears.  I have set everything up using the wizards in Visual Studio 2010, so I'm still not 100% familiar with what all the various TableAdapters and DataSets do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question seems to be about databinding a ComboBox, but the title is talking about TextBoxes.  Can you clarify that a bit?

Comment: @LarsTech - sorry about that.  I have updated the title to ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't have the ComboBox databinded (databound?) to both tables at the same time — they would be fighting each other as to which value should be displayed in the ComboBox and would most likely end up corrupting your data tables with the wrong data.

You would either need a separate ComboBox for each tab, or change the databinding of the ComboBox based on the current tab.

Comment: I understand they would be fighting each other for which value to show, but in this case, they would show the same value due to the relationships between tables.

Comment: If TableB.A_ID and TableC.A_ID are always referring to the same A_ID, then it's not an issue.  But there wasn't any evidence of that in the post.  It seems like TableB and TableC could be referring to different A_ID values.

Comment: If they're showing the same value, why do you need to bind to both?

Comment: I guess I should clarify...The idea is that the user would select a TableA.A_ID value from the combobox, then they could select one of the associated records in TableB in tab B and one of the associated records in TableC in tab C.  They would also have the option to create new records in TableB or TableC that would be automatically related to whatever A_ID is selected in the combobox.

Comment: Okay, so do you want to select, say, 12345 from the combobox and then only display any record with that number in the FK column for the tables in tab B & C? Then, you want the ability to add something to B (or C) and have it automatically relate to A?